# fetch value from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table t1:

```
c1 c2 
1  a
2  b
3  a
```

table t2:

```
c3  c4
4    1
5    2
6    3
```

I am writing a procedure:

```
select c1 from t1 where c2 = 'a';
```

which will give multiple outputs. Use that output (1,3)

```
select c3 from t2 where c4 = 1,

select c3 from t2 where c4 = 3 -- out put of first query;
```

How do I implement it ? Should i use any loops? If so, how do I loop or how do I write a procedure which returns the result of it?

Comment: That's really very basic SQL. Before writing procedures, you should learn the basics. Any SQL tutorial, even the worst of them, explains joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use join

```
select c1,c3 from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.c1=t2.c4
where c2='a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to work more on it but this is how i think this can be implemented.Inside the SP create a table data type where you can insert the multiple values fetched and then you can pass these values to another SP as a table value parameters where you can do the rest of the operations.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use** `in`

```
select c3 from t2 where c4 in
(select c1 from t1 where c2 = 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1,c3 from t1,t2
where t1.c1=t2.c4 and  c2='a'
```